# Star Trek: TOS episode involving aliens with mental powers and a tormented dwarf

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

In this episode, an away team from the Enterprise (standard team with Kirk, Spock and McCoy) encounter a small community of humanoid aliens who all have psychokinetic abilities, except for a dwarf that the others bully. McCoy thinks he can find a way to give the dwarf the same powers as the others, but the dwarf refuses because he doesn't want to become "like them".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is *Star Trek: The Original Series* S03E12, **"[Plato's Stepchildren](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Plato%27s_Stepchildren_(episode))"** (1968).

> The Enterprise finds a planet inhabited by aliens who were once followers of the Greek philosopher Plato.

The 'dwarf' character is [Alexander](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alexander).

> **Alexander was a resident of Platonius who, unlike the other Platonians, did not have the power of psychokinesis.** He was a person of extraordinarily short stature who served as court buffoon and slave to the other Platonians.
>
> [...]
>
> **Enterprise chief medical officer Leonard McCoy later determined that the others got their power from the food native to Platonius which contained kironide, a substance that after being assimilated by the pituitary gland promoted psychokinesis.** Unfortunately, since dwarfism stemmed from a malfunction in that gland that also regulated body growth, Alexander did not have the psionic ability.
>
> [...]
>
> Alexander agreed to help the Enterprise crew escape. **McCoy synthesized the kironide and injected himself, Kirk, and Spock. They offered Alexander an injection, but he refused to get a dose out of disgust for his fellow Platonians' laziness and cruelty.**

Comment: Also the famous "kiss" episode!

Comment: What always bothered me about that episode was the total *lack* of follow-up on the idea that psychokinetic abilities could now be given to anyone with a simple injection.

Comment: @Lorendiac- Maybe they were worried how some people might put those abilities to use.